# Overriding get_context_data() is not working in child view

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am trying to override `get_context_data()` in a child class-based view to send more contextual data to the template, but it doesn't work. As a sample I am sending a test variable, but it is not rendered in the template.

```
class ProductList(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
   template_name = 'product/product_scroll.html'
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #...
        return render(request, self.template_name, data)  

class Feed(ProductList):
    template_name = "product/feed.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['test'] = 'sometestinfo'
        return context
```

But in the template:

```
 <p> Prueba: {{test}} </p>
```

is empty.

Comment: Check if `get_context_data` is being called. If it isn't then perhaps you're calling that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you override `get`. Therefore the whole built in functionality of the view - including calling `get_context_data` - is bypassed. You almost never need to define the get or post methods.

Comment: Thank you. I set some contextual variables in the overriden get method of the parent template and render the template. Where all that functionality should be moved to not override the get method so get_context_data of child classes could work?

Comment: You should put them in the get_context_data of the parent view. That's exactly what it's for.